# How can I rotate my barchart around a circle in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3 and am essentially trying to wrap a bar chart around a circle. I have the code so far that creates my bars and places them in a circle, but I can't figure out how to rotate each individual bar so that the chart looks like the bars are pointing outwards from the circle (kind of like a sunburst plot). Here's the code I use to modify each rectangle:

```
 var rectangle = svg.append("g")
                    .selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                            .attr("x", function(d){return 160 * Math.cos(d.angle/(11/2) * Math.PI) + 250})
                            .attr("y", function(d){return 160 * Math.sin(d.angle/(11/2) * Math.PI) + 250})
                            .attr("width", 30)
                            .attr("height", function(d){return size(d.tuition)})
                            .style("fill", "#B9975B")
                            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                            .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                            .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
```

})

I have tried transforming each bar using transform and rotate but that rotates the whole grouping of bars instead of each individual one. How do I rotate each bar so that they are facing outwards from the center of the circle?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Have you checked this example of the radial stacked barchart by Mike Bostock? https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-stacked-bar-chart

Comment: I hadn't seen this example, thank you!

Comment: No worries @pb_waffles. Glad to help. Do post your solution once you have it as it may help others.